# Differentiating $x \mapsto \cos^2(x)$ in two different ways

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

When $\cos^2(x)$ is differentiated via the chain rule, its outcome is $-2\cos(x)\sin(x)$.

However when the double angle formula is applied to $\cos^2(x)$, it becomes $$\frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2x))$$ which when differentiated is just $-\sin(x)$. How can this be?

Comment: You didn't differentiate $x\mapsto \dfrac 1 2 \left(1+\cos(2x)\right)$ correctly.

Comment: This site uses [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Not all features of $\LaTeX$ are compatible with Mathjax.  In particular, mathematics must be enclosed by dollar signs.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of the second expression is $$-\sin(2x),$$ not $-\sin(x)$ and it can because $$ \sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x).$$

Answer (score 2):

$$-2\sin(x)\cos(x)=-\sin(2x)$$
And your second expression's derivative is
$$\frac{1}{2}(-2\sin(2x))=-\sin(2x)$$